# Codeigniter - client posted links with capital letters in URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, lowercase

my client has printed links to the site in capital letters.
I have a CI install and need to change htaccess or the base controller (I'm trying lots of options at the mo) to work like these examples (it a user types this into their address bar):

http://www.site.com/HAPPY/chappy -> http://www.site.com/happy/chappy

http://www.SITE.com/HaPpy/CHAPpy -> http://www.site.com/happy/chappy

http://WWW.Site.CoM/happy/chappY -> http://www.site.com/happy/chappy

and so on...
I can't seem to get htaccess to simply say 'take everything in, turn it to lower case then process it'

is this even possible..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can convert input to small letters as soon as text has been entered. You can do it with javascript. refer below code snipe for it.

```
function makeLowercase() {
document.form1.outstring.value = document.form1.instring.value.toLowerCase();
}

<input name="outstring" type="text" value="" size="30" onkeyup="makeLowercase();" onblur="makeLowercase();">
```

OR you can use  **strtolower()** function in PHP to covert data in to lower case and process it.

Comment: Cheers.. I did put this in the index page of my instillation:
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

No change.. all the above examples still all went to 404 pages, rather than re-writing. Am I a monkey.. is this not the right approach?

Comment: no it's not working.. simply does nothing... FYi this si when a user takes a fresh browser and types in teh URL

Comment: This is javascript, which doesn't address the stated problem. Neither is changing the routing config going to help with the exception of setting a 404_override and creating a controller that will do essentially what I stated in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess to rewrite the part after hostname (that one is case-insensitive anyway):

http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/

Comment: Putting this:

`code``
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
`code

Into my htaccess file causes the site to fail with a server error

Comment: removing this line `RewriteMap lc int:tolower` removes the server error... what exactly is this line doing?

Answer (score 0):

[Extend the CI_Exceptions core class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) with your own `show_error` function.  Use the original code for `show_error`, but add a quick check to the beginning along these lines:

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

    /**
     * General Error Page
     *
     * This function takes an error message as input
     * (either as a string or an array) and displays
     * it using the specified template.
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string  the heading
     * @param   string  the message
     * @param   string  the template name
     * @return  string
     */
    function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $status_code = 500)
    {
        // First try forwarding to all-lowercase URL if there were caps in the request
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
        {
            header('Location: ' . strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
            return;
        }
        /* Rest of original function to follow... */
```

Customize as necessary, keeping in mind other parts of the URI that you might want to have uppercase.

You could also achieve the similar functionality with a [pre_system (or pre_controller) hook](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html), though I'd personally only do that if hooks are already enabled for another purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the core routing library to be case-insensitive. That's where you'd put your `strtolower()` function.

Adding it to the 404 error handler is a bad idea.

If you want source, LMK, but it should be a matter of extending the library, copying 1 function, and adding `strtolower()`.